# why am I getting a negative value in taking a timestamp?

Tags: c, linux, time, timestamp, uint32

```
Uint64_t a;
Uint32 b;

a= clock_cycles();
b= uint32((a*1000000)/(SYSPAGE_ENTRY(qtime)->cycles_per_sec));
printf("RECEIVE from Time in microseconds: %ld\n",  b);
```

I created the variable and taking the timestamp and converting that into uint32 as shown in the above code.

If I print the b value then I am getting negative value!!
What's wrong in doing like above ??

Answer (score 1):

Your b is larger than 2^31. Printf format "%ld" indicates you are going to print a signed integer and printf interprets numbers with highest bit as negative integers. Use "%lu" instead of "%ld".

Also when looking at your code, the numeric value of `a*1000000` is very probable to overflow over maximal possible value. In your case, I'd suggest to use another function to get microsecond time, for example `gettimeofday` and to store the result in a 64-bit integer.

Comment: If you change it to %lu you will not get negative values. However the problem of arithmetic overflow may cause that you will get wrong values.